# How to create a ListView of Buttons that play different sounds on click

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-button, android-imagebutton

I need to make an Activity with a ListView that could have more than 50 ImageButtons that each play a different Sound.

This is the main activity (that would have the buttons):

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context="com.werewolve.freaksound.sounds"
    android:background="@drawable/f_background_fit">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/f_logo" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/soundList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my custom layout for each line of the listview:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/f_button_s"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each button will play a different sound with the onClick "play_btn" and a text according to the sound with the string "list_item_string".

Example:

---

*** (Laugh Sound) *** (Play Button) ***

---

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom adapter like so:

```
public class PlaySoundsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    SoundExample[] sounds;
    Activity context;
    PlaySoundAlert soundPlayerAlert;

    public PlaySoundsAdapter(Activity context, SoundExample[] soundsArray) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sounds = soundsArray;

        // Hooks up the PlaySoundAlert.PlaySound in MainActivity
        this.soundPlayerAlert = (PlaySoundAlert)context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sounds == null ? 0 : sounds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return sounds[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        SoundExample item = (SoundExample)getItem(i);

        if (view == null) // reuse existing view
            view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_sound_layout,
                    viewGroup, false);

        // Set the TextView to the name of the sound
        TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        t.setText(item.getSoundName());

        // Set the tag of the button to the sound resource id (uri)
        Button b = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
        b.setTag(item.getSoundUri());

        // When the button is clicked, play the associated sound
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button b = (Button) view;
        if (b != null) {
            int soundUri = (int)b.getTag();

            // Notify listener (MainActivity) to play the required sound
            if (soundPlayerAlert != null) {
                soundPlayerAlert.playSound(soundUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next create an interface you can implement in your activity to play a sound like this:

```
public interface PlaySoundAlert {
    public void playSound(int uri);
}
```

As you can see the `Adapter` I created above uses this interface to fire off an event to play the required sound.

Your `SoundExample` class might like something like this:

```
public class SoundExample {

    private int soundUri;
    private String soundName;

    public String getSoundName() {
        return soundName;
    }

    public void setSoundName(String soundName) {
        this.soundName = soundName;
    }

    public int getSoundUri() {
        return soundUri;
    }

    public void setSoundUri(int soundUri) {
        this.soundUri = soundUri;
    }
}
```

And to use this inside your `Activity` or `Fragment` use the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements PlaySoundAlert {

    ListView lstSounds;
    PlaySoundsAdapter soundsAdapter;
    SoundExample[] mySounds;

    // Media player for playing sounds
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstSounds = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.soundList);

        // Create sound list & add two SoundExample objects
        mySounds = new SoundExample[2];
        SoundExample s1 = new SoundExample();
        SoundExample s2 = new SoundExample();

        // Set sound one to a beep
        s1.setSoundName("Beep Sound");
        s1.setSoundUri(R.raw.beep);

        // Set sound two to an applause sound
        s2.setSoundName("Applause Sound");
        // NOTE: I am using a sound titled applause.mp3 inside a folder called "raw"
        s2.setSoundUri(R.raw.applause);

        // Add sounds to the list
        mySounds[0] = s1;
        mySounds[1] = s2;

        // Instantiate the adapter and apply to the ListView
        soundsAdapter = new PlaySoundsAdapter(this, mySounds);
        lstSounds.setAdapter(soundsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void playSound(int uri) {
        // Play sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
        if (!mp.isPlaying())
            mp.start();
    }
}
```

And that should be all you need!

Comment: I have added all you coded to my app.. changed some things that were not let me compile the app.. and finnally compiled it..  BUT, how do I add a new row with text and sound path to the list?

Comment: @ElAlonnso see my update. Note I have changed the `SoundExample soundUri` to an int. You will also need to add your sound or media files in a directory called `raw`.

Comment: HERE: OK, now it throw me the following errors:

(13, 37) error: cannot find symbol class PlaySoundAlert.
Error:
(47, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.

May it be because I have changed some Private Classes to Public because those were send me "error"?..

AND: Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.play_btn); (says Incompatible Types Android.Widget.Button and Android.View.View)

Comment: It sounds like you're missing `public interface PlaySoundAlert`. You must make sure your `play_btn` is a `Button` otherwise you will get an incompatible type error.

Comment: Change `Button b = view.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);` to `Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);`

Comment: Now.. LogCat Error: Unable to start Activity (main) sounds.. on line 37.. I will look up..

AND in my java files there are: sounds, SoundExample and PlaySoundsAdapter classes.. and I had the PlaySoundAlert interface.. but I put deleted it and put into PlaySoundsAdapter..

LATER: If it could help you with helping me.. I will send how I've put all the files in.. TY

Comment: Error is here --> Line #37: lstSounds.setAdapter(soundsAdapter);

Comment: Ok.. this is the folder with all you write.. (I think it may help you)

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qo2lhjtsbrrdxvi/AABwxjUgoRh79yQx9Ntlop_va?dl=0

Comment: Here is the link for [Classes and the Logcat Error](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qo2lhjtsbrrdxvi/AABwxjUgoRh79yQx9Ntlop_va?dl=0) I have put in thes folder..

Comment: It looks like your `ListView` might be `null`. Have you initiated your `ListView`? `ListView lstView = view.findViewById(R.id.soundList);`.

Comment: Added this:ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.soundList);
        listView.setAdapter(soundsAdapter);

Below this: ... mySounds[1] = s2;

        soundsAdapter = new PlaySoundsAdapter(this, mySounds);
        lstSounds.setAdapter(soundsAdapter); ... in MAINACTIVITY (sounds.java)

But Still The error.... And I dont know realy how to initiate my ListView :/..

Comment: @ElAlonnso I have added a complete working example of what you need. Please see my edit.

Comment: Your first and second editions have a bunch of errors at first put.. but THE THIRD is only throwing me one.. in the line: int soundUri = (int)b.getTag(); of PlaySoundsAdapter.. (In android studio).. saying me cannot cast java.lang.object to int :/.. --- I read the code.. and looks great.. but it say me those red words :/// ---

Comment: Hmmm strange, I have run this in Android Studio and can confirm it is working. Do you see this error when running or in design time? You may also try replace with `Integer soundUri = (Integer)b.getTag();`.

Comment: MAN.. MAN.. MAN.. NOW IT WORKS PERFECTLY!!.. EXACTLY WHAT I WANT.. YOU ARE SO ATTENDED FOR MY QUESTION.. YOU HAVE MY CONGRATULATIONS.. AND SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH BECAUSE I REALLY SPEAK SPANISH.. BUT YOU ARE BIG MAN THANKS YOU.. I WILL PUT YOU IN MY CREDITS PAGE OF MY APP TY!!!!

Comment: Ahh.. and.. Change that last error that was Integer soundUri = (Integer)b.getTag(); the solution to your edition.. for help other people too.. :D!

Comment: this is freaking awesome!

Comment: Perhaps comments aren't the most suitable way to express this, but I am ElAlonnso. This marked my first steps into app development when I was 15 years old, and it likely represents my earliest foray into programming.

Despite the fact that the app was removed due to copyright issues (as it was an unofficial soundboard for a renowned Spanish YouTuber), it managed to accumulate over 150,000 downloads. I will forever be grateful for your support and assistance.

Comment: @TIBI4 Haha that's great to know! I must have had a lot of spare time that night by the looks of it :D ... Hope your career turned out prosperous and many more apps written since then!

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to create a custom `ListView` object that has both a `TextView` for displaying the name of the button and an `ImageButton`. You then add these objects to your `ListView` by using a custom `Adapter`. An alternative to the `ImageButton` is to simply use a regular image and make it `Clickable`. A great example for creating a `ListView` that can display custom objects (including how to create the custom `Adapter`) may be found here: http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/